# Parsing out indeces and values from pandas multi index dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in a similar format to this:

```
+--------+--------+----------+------+------+------+------+
|        |        |          |      | day1 | day2 | day3 |
+--------+--------+----------+------+------+------+------+
| id_one | id_two | id_three | date |      |      |      |
| 18273  | 50     | 1        | 3    |    9 |   11 |    3 |
|        |        |          | 4    |   26 |   27 |   68 |
|        |        |          | 5    |   92 |   25 |    4 |
|        |        |          | 6    |   60 |   72 |   83 |
|        | 60     | 2        | 5    |   69 |   93 |   84 |
|        |        |          | 6    |   69 |   30 |   12 |
|        |        |          | 7    |   65 |   65 |   59 |
|        |        |          | 8    |   57 |   88 |   59 |
|        | 70     | 3        | 5    |   22 |   95 |    7 |
|        |        |          | 6    |   40 |   24 |   20 |
|        |        |          | 7    |   73 |   81 |   57 |
|        |        |          | 8    |   43 |    8 |   66 |
+--------+--------+----------+------+------+------+------+
```

I am trying to create tuple that contains `id_one`, `id_two` and the values that each grouping contains.

To test this, I am simply trying to print the ids and values like this:

```
for id_two, data in df.head(100).groupby(level='id_two'):
    print id_two, data.values.ravel()
```

Which gives me the `id_two` and the data exactly as it should.

I am running into problems when I try and incorporate `id_one`.  I tried this, but was met with an error `ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack`

```
for id_one, id_two, data in df.head(100).groupby(level='id_two'):
    print id_one, id_two, data.values.ravel()
```

How can I print `id_one`, `id_two` and the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a list of columns into the `level` parameter:

```
df.head.groupby(level=['id_one', 'id_two'])
```